# How to split string to dictionary using multiple separators as a key

Tags: c#, string

I have string that looks like this:

```
var givenString = "Id: some id Title: sometitle Descritpion: some description Criteria: some criteria <br>more criteria"
```

How can i split it into dictionary where separator is key and value is from given string. Also there is possibility that one of the separators is not in the text.

I know how to split it into sentence but don't know how to handle situation when one of the separators is missing and how to split it to dictionary.

```
string[] separators = { "Id:", "Title:", "Descritpion", "Criteria:" }; 
string[] words = givenString.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**EDIT1:**
Sample with missing separator:

```
var givenString = "Id: some id Title: sometitle Criteria: some criteria <br>more criteria"
```

**EDIT2**
I forget that some separators can be two words :(. If it make easier I can ask to change separators to be written by uppercase letter:

```
var givenString = "ID: some id TITLE: sometitle CRITERIA: some criteria <br>more criteria, DIFFERENT CRITERIA: some criteria <br>more criteria"
```

Comment: can you give the sample string when separators is missing?

Comment: I add example you ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to split on *pattern* (letters `A..Za..z` followed by column `:`) I suggest using *regular expressions*, [Regex.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `givenString.Split`:

```
string givenString = 
  @"Id: some id Title: sometitle Descritpion: some description Criteria: some criteria <br>more criteria";

Dictionary<string, string> result = Regex
  .Split(givenString, "([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+:)|([A-Z][a-z]+:)") 
  .Skip(1)                            // <- skip (empty) chunk before the 1st separator
  .Select((item, index) => new {      // pair: separator followed by value 
     value = item.Trim(), 
     index = index / 2 })
  .GroupBy(item => item.index)
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.First().value.TrimEnd(':'), 
                chunk => chunk.Last().value);
```

Test:

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(pair => $"Key = {pair.Key,-12} Value = \"{pair.Value}\""));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
Key = Id           Value = "some id"
Key = Title        Value = "sometitle"
Key = Descritpion  Value = "some description"
Key = Criteria     Value = "some criteria <br>more criteria"
```

Comment: Works almost perfect. What if for exampel i have 
'Pass Criteria:' inseted of just 'Criteria'. Is there a way that regex will capture it?

Comment: I figure it out. I use regex: "([A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+:)|([A-Z][a-z]+:)"

Comment: @kendzi: you are quite right, if separators must start each word with *capital* letter